# node https get request to public api results in Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED

Tags: node.js, api, https, get, request

trying to perform a simple https request to a public api but i'm getting "Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED"

```
require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'btc-e.com',
  path: '/api/2/btc_usd/ticker',
  port: '443',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {accept:'*/*'}
};

var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
 console.log(res.statusCode);
 res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
 });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it! I just had to update my node installation using the following commands:

sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable